# Accepting HTML email form inputs with PHP on cpanel

Tags: php, html, forms, email, cpanel

I have created an HTML form and need help with email submissions using PHP on a cPanel server. I have no experience with PHP or cPanel and this is what I have. On my cPanel server, I have both my index.html and process_form.php under my public_html folder in file manager.

I think it's an issue with my code more than the cPanel server? All I need as of right now is a functioning email contact form, I have no idea why my emails aren't sending to the $mailTo address. I want my emails to include the senders name, email, message and phone number.

This doesn't return any errors in my cPanel error log, but no email is being shown in my gmail.

Here is my HTML code

```
<section id="contact">
        <div class="header2">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hero">
            <form action="process_form.php" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
                    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="number" name="number" required>
                    <label for="number">Phone no.</label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
                <label for="email">Email Id</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea id="message" rows="8" name="message" required></textarea>
                <label for="message">Your message</label>
            </div>
            <button class="submit_btn" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

        </form>


    </div>

</section>
```

along with what i have for my php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $mailTo = "contact@company.ca";
    $headers = "From: " .$email;

    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;
    // Send email
    $success = mail($mailTo, $number, $message, $headers);
    // Check if the email was sent successfully
    if ($success) {
        // Display a thank you message
        echo "<p>Thank you for your submission! We will get back to you shortly.</p>";
    } else {
        // Display an error message
        echo "<p>Error sending email. Please try again.</p>";
    }
//sends you to the top of the webpage
    header("Location: index.html?mailsend");
}
?>
```

Comment: The _code_ for sending email is very simple. The [reasons why is doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/231316) are many.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to how you handle headers try like

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $mailTo = "contact@company.ca";
    $subject = "New Contact Form Submission";

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $name <$email>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";

    $txt = "You have received a message from $name ($email).\n\n";
    $txt .= "Phone Number: $number\n\n";
    $txt .= "Message:\n$message";

    $success = mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);

    if ($success) {
        echo "<p>Thank you for your submission! We will get back to you shortly.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Error sending email. Please try again.</p>";
    }
    
    header("Location: index.html?mailsend");
    exit();
}
```